# Tyre swapping on corsa 2013

Tags: tires, vauxhall, corsa

I need a advice. I had one front tyre damaged, side cut on tyre so i ordered two new tyres and had them replaced at the tyre fitting place. Other front tyre was in grate condition so i asked a fitter if he could swap that tyre with one of the back tyres coz it has little bulge on it. He said he can do it and i will need two new tyres for back as well, because it would affect tyre pressure monitoring system and alarm would go off. Is this true or was i ripped off by making me to buy two new tyres. Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you help us a little by giving us the vehicle information? Year/make/model/engine/transmission information would be awesome! EDIT! Just saw you included the year/model info in the title. The other info would be awesome, though.

Comment: Its vauxhall corsa 2013, 1.2 petrol, manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were the front tires identical to rear tires?

So, let me get this straight... One front tire was damaged, you ordered two. Then you said you want the other old front tire back to the rear, and now the tire fitter immediately thought you need two new rear tires as well.

Sounds like you were being ripped off, if the old front tires are identical to the old rear tires. You can perfectly well swap identical with identical.

Also, the passive TPMS warning isn't fatal. You could perfectly well test whether it results in TPMS warning, and if it does, you can choose to either ignore the warning or replace the rear tires as well.

Strange that the tire fitter didn't ask you to test first whether the TPMS warning appears.

Don't buy the new rear tires. Test first whether the TPMS warning appears (it probably doesn't).

Comment: Basically, one front tyre was damaged and other was in great condition. I know u should always swap two tyres at the time, so i ordered two new tyres to put on front. I wanted to use good front tyre at the back because it was in better condition but the tyre fitter said he cant do that coz it will affect TPMS

Comment: Don't believe everything they say. Test yourself whether the TPMS warning appears. If the tire fitter doesn't move the other tire to the rear, find a better tire fitter. Or learn to change the wheels on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your help, im goona make a complain about the the place and will see whaf they gonna do about it